# How to use interface{} as flexible function argument and return type?

Tags: function, go, parameters, casting

I'm a beginner with Go, and I'm now writing a function which can call an API. The function receives a part of the url (`/user`, `/account`, etc) and the struct to convert the returned json to (the structs `User` or `Account` for example) as arguments.

So I now have this:

```
func (self *RestClient) request(action string, return_type interface{}) interface{} {
    res, _ := goreq.Request{Uri:self.url + action}.Do()
    var item return_type
    res.Body.FromJsonTo(&item)
    return item
}
```

And I try to call this function using (with `Index` being the struct for the return type):

```
self.request("/api/v1/public/index", Index)
```

But this doesn't work. I get the following errors:

```
return_type is not a type
type Index is not an expression
```

I guess I understand why this is. I think I have to somehow find out the type of `return_type` and then convert `return_type` to that type, before using it as the type for `item`. I have no idea how though.
About the second error I have no idea. I don't even understand what is meant by it.

Could anybody help me out? How can I make this work? Or should this be done in a completely different way all together? All tips are welcome!

Comment: This can be done but it is ugly. As a beginner don't try to fight Go's static typing. You could write three different functions with static types. Given that the function is 4 lines long this is okay. Once you mastered Go you could pass in a pointer to the result. This would work very well with the empty interface and there would be no need to return anything. For now: Write statically typed code is the best advice I can give.

Comment: @Volker - Unfortunately the function is not 4 lines in my code, more like 25. It also includes authentication using jwt. So I would like to keep it one function. If I need to keep this one function, are there any other ways you could suggest?

Comment: Then it will be 25 lines of code. My suggestion is: Do not fight the type system as a beginner. And no, I won't suggest reflection to a beginner. Btw. Your code would work if you dropped returning the value.

Answer (score 4):

A few hints based on this code:

- Don't use self - use a meaningful identifier
- Don't use interface{} to avoid dealing with the type system
- Don't use reflection
- Don't ignore errors returned (as from FromJsonTo or goreq.Request)
- Don't use a library like goreq unless you are sure you need it (you don't) - you are pulling in [lots](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/franela/goreq@b5b0f5eb2d16f20345cce0a544a75163579c0b00/-/blob/goreq.go#L276:18) of code you don't need and it is teaching you bad habits like attempting to use empty interface and reflection to solve simple problems.

Have a look at the definition of [FromJsonTo](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/franela/goreq@b5b0f5eb2d16f20345cce0a544a75163579c0b00/-/blob/goreq.go#L117:16) - if you look through this library you'll see it isn't saving you much effort and is adding lots of complexity. Here is how you could do it without the library:

```
func (c *RestClient) Request(action string, resource interface{}) error {
    res, err := http.Get(c.url + action)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(resource)
}
```

Or use an interface and move the decoding to the resource (which could embed a default decoder):

```
type Decoder interface {
    Decode(r io.Reader) error
}

// RequestDecode fetches a request and feeds it to the decoder
func (c *RestClient) RequestDecode(action string, resource Decoder) error {
    res, err := http.Get(c.url + action)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return resource.Decode(res.Body)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll first say that you should always check for errors from any function that possibly returns one.

The error you are seeing is because you are trying to declare a variable `item` as type `return_type` and that is the name of a function argument.

The other error is from `Index` being a type declaration and not a concrete value of the `Index` type.

I agree with Volker's comment but to put it in code, you could use something like this:

```
func (self *RestClient) request(action string, return_type interface{}) {
    res, err := goreq.Request{Uri:self.url + action}.Do()
    if err != nil {
        // Do something with error here.
    }
    res.Body.FromJsonTo(return_type)
}

var index Index
rest_client.request("/some/path", &index)
```

This allows flexibility but could lead to strange cases if you forget to pass a pointer to the value `return_type`.